# gridlines in highstocks for each category

Tags: javascript, formatting, highcharts, gridlines

I'm trying to get a gridline for each category but in my code I set up the categories instead of using the x datetime coordinates.

How would I do this with highstocks?

I tried this with no luck

```
 xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: '%b of %Y'   
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        },
        minorGridLineColor: '#E0E0E0'
    },
```

here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pradeepbhat92/VuDJ7/

Comment: Can you explain it better and provide a working demo ?

Answer (score 0):

You would like to get gridLines position or add your custom lines? In second part of question, you can use plotLines.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.plotLines